# New to Git - production and staging environment

Tags: git, github

I'm new to Git and I'd like to implement this in my workflow. I have a website with two directories:

- public_html (production)
- staging

I'd like to make changes on staging and move those to public_html once they're tested well. At the moment I'm using GitHub in between. So from staging I'm using:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Then the staging will be pushed to GitHub's private repo

From the public_html (production folder) I'll call:

```
git pull origin master
```

Is this the best workflow for me? 99% of the time I'm working solo by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the version control system and the release packaging are two different concept. When you use git for version control, all files related to a release are tracked, they maybe internal design documents, source code for some libraries, supporting development tool, private key files etc that are necessary to build a version, but should not be deployed in production environment.

In your case it sounds like you will deploy everything to your production server. A better workflow is you should have a simple release packaging program, which can be as simple as a script/batch file to copy only necessary files and perhaps create one single .zip file. The script should also be tracked in git.

When you finish testing, you should commit everything and tag a version. Then use the packaging script to build that zip file and simple unzip to your public_html for release

Comment: Yes. The OP should not conflate version control systems and release artifact repositories. For some types of files they just happen to have the same contents.